# change war/jar name after build in jenkins before deployment to artifactory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

We are trying to setup a jenkins job where in we would like to change the change the name of the final artifact that is built to something like `<app_name>_<branch_name>_<environment>.<war/jar>` before deploying it to artifactory. We dont want to add this through our pom.xml. Is there a way to do this through jenkins using any plugins?

Our aim to store artifacts at each stage (dev/qa/prod).

Comment: You could just use _Execute Shell_ build step in job configuration page where you would use a simple `mv` command passed with your artifact name. **Tip** - You could use a lot of environment variables available in jenkins [ref](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-below) to make your artifact name dynamic accordingly.

Comment: @rusia.inc there is no execute shell step available in build stage for a maven jenkins job. there is however a post build step, executing a  mv command here changes the name of the war/jar in the jenkins workspace but doesnt change the name when it is deployed to artifactory

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but I do have a question:  If the aim is to store artifacts for each environment, why not use classifiers or qualified version numbers, which would conform more closely to standard naming?  `someProject-1.0.0-qa.jar` or similar? With that approach I would think the build environments could be coaxed into creating the right name from the beginning...